# Capacity vs. Ability

Tags: difference, synonyms

> **Capable.** "Men are capable of being flattered." Say, susceptible to flattery. "Capable of being refuted." Vulnerable to refutation. Unlike
>   capacity, capability is not passive, but active. We are capable of
>   doing, not of having something done to us.
>
> **Capacity for Ability.** "A great capacity for work." Capacity is receptive; ability, potential. A sponge has capacity for water; the hand, ability to squeeze it out.
>
> *Write It Right: A Little Blacklist of Literary Faults* by Ambrose Bierce

I suppose this excerpt is not very accurate. The distinction between capacity and ability isn't as clear-cut as is said above. The rule only applies to a limited number of examples.

I'd like to know what a native speaker would say about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capacity is more often used to describe the levels of the abilities of something (often the containing capabilities) and not the abilities of that thing itself. For example, my water bottle has the **capacity** of 500mL but the **ability** to hold water. The capacity describes the ability. Although capacity can be used in place of ability, it is generally not used as much. Capacity is a synonym for ability, but it also has another, more common meaning, that refers to the containing abilities of an object. It acts more like the word **capability** than **ability**.

[capacity](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20capacity), n.

1.the maximum amount that something can contain.

2.the ability or power to do, experience, or understand something.